# Sending requests from one machine to 1000 or more than 1000 different machines over HTTP in java

Tags: http

If I have 1000 or more than 1000 clients and I want to send request turn by turn to all 1000 clients I have, Is it advisable to use HTTP/S ? Will it become heavy for the machine sending request ? What other protocol I can use to do this ?

**UPDATE**

I had asked the wrong question previously. . .I have edited it. I want to send request turn by turn and not at the same time.

Comment: Have you given any thought to using a load balancer?

Comment: You could do tcp/udp sockets!

Comment: I haven't thought about Load balancer , , because the request will be sent by a centralized sever . . and there isn't any other entity which can do that  in my project . . so the response also will come at one place only . .

Comment: How TCP will benefit me over HTTP ?

Comment: check for multicast, as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast, this is used for video streaming for example, HTTP is more a client->server protocol (where the client initiate the dialog, and the durability of the connection is hard to maintain). Check with HTTP2 push technology also.